# Payment section on checkout progress block is updating wrong details

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-1.8, onepage-checkout, payment-methods

Payment section on checkout progress block is updating wrong details.
When you select saved cc method as payment method and click on continue after filling up all the required fields. the progress block updates itself with the details I have added in saved cc form.
[image]

Now, when I click on payment method again and select paypal as my payment method,
[image]
[image]
It updates the payment section on progress block but it also displays me the credit card number.
Any help will be much appreciated.
Attached is the screenshot for my PayPal payment method.
[image]

Comment: Do you have any 3rd party extensions installed? If yes, try disabling them one by one. Also If you have any theme modifications try to revert them also.

Comment: You tagged this question with both `magento-1.7` and `magento-1.8`. Does it mean you are experiencing the issue in both versions?

Comment: I have just tried this on fresh Magento installation with the same results. with both on Magento 1.7 and Magento 1.8.

Comment: What type of PayPal are you using? With just "Credit Card (saved)" and "Check / Money order" the problem is not reproducible.

Comment: I am using PayPal Payment Standard. I have added a screenshot to my question for my payment method.

Comment: Can you check the XHR /checkout/onepage/savePayment/ via your browser console? 

if this one doesn't have error, this one /checkout/onepage/progress/?toStep=review should return correct response.

Comment: does you know about payeezy payment gateway

Comment: @Rathinam, sorry but I am not aware of it

Comment: could u pls help me about fedex confugration

Comment: You can check http://docs.magento.com/m1/ce/user_guide/shipping/fedex.html or http://inchoo.net/magento/how-to-set-fedex-shipping-in-magento/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got the solution by overriding Paypal Info Block.
I updated

```
class Mage_Paypal_Block_Payment_Info extends Mage_Payment_Block_Info_Cc
```

to

```
class Mage_Paypal_Block_Payment_Info extends Mage_Payment_Block_Info
```

Now I don't see any information related to CC Save method with paypal Details.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

`Mage_Paypal_Block_Payment_Info` extends `Mage_Payment_Block_Info_Cc` and calls the parent `_prepareSpecificInformation` function. Since the quote still contains the credit cards information, when it gets to this conditional:

```
if ($this->getInfo()->getCcLast4()) {
    $data[Mage::helper('payment')->__('Credit Card Number')] = sprintf('xxxx-%s', $this->getInfo()->getCcLast4());
}
```

the credit card number is added to the data returned for display. Seems like `Mage_Paypal_Block_Payment_Info` should override `getCcLast4` and return nothing like it does with `getCcTypeName`.